# Adding image to blog post (featured)

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I want to add an image which will be displayed on the recent blog post widget shown on my home page. 
I am using orchard 1.8.1

I am finding a lot of information that seems to be out/outdated and not applicable to 1.8.1 (i.e. the designer tools module 1.6 does not work in 1.8.1)

Where can i find information on how to add change the content of the recent blog posts part to show the newly added feature image (added to the blog post content type)

Little frustrating because the shapes feature is enabled but nothing is visible either. Not sure if broken/changed or what.

Comment: A few questions: Why would you want to install designer tools 1.6 on 1.8.1 whereas 1.8.1 comes with a perfectly good version of that module out of the box? How did you build that featured image? Is it a media library picker field? What is that recent blog posts part? Isn't it simply displaying the posts in summary display mode?

Comment: Looking at `RecentBlogPostPartDriver` it builds the display based on a list in summary type display, so changing it in the Placement.info should do the trick